# Toggle roweditor to be active for all rows all the time

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there a way to activate the roweditor (or celleditor) for all visible rows? I've looked into be API but found nothing. I also tried to set the activation clicks to 0 without any success. I need to show a checkbox, a combobox and a spinnerfield all the time.

So can that done at all? Or is there any other plugin to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is now way to do this and setting **clicksToEdit** to any value lower then 1 or greater then 2 is not valid.

If you want archive anything like that you might need to write your own plugin by extending the roweditor.